# How to search for a line which contains specific string in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sed, awk

I've got a file which contains some amount of lines, I want to look for a specific string, and if the file contains it, then I want  to print a different line from the same file.
for example, let's assume I have the file:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Let's say that I'm looking for `bbb`, and if I find it I want to print the following line (in the example, `ccc`).

I know that with *grep*  I can easily search for the "bbb", but what command can I use in order to print a different line of the same file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are these options in `grep`:

**-A *NUM*** will give you `NUM` lines after.

**-B NUM*** will give you `NUM` lines before.

**-C NUM** both (`NUM` lines before and `NUM` lines after).

Where ***NUM*** is an integer number.

In your case `grep -A 1 bbb file.txt` will give you `ccc`.